# check and uncheck checkbox in angular 2 via spacebar

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am new to angular 2 and trying to implement one checkbox functionality i.e checkbox should get checked and unchecked once i hit spacebar.

Code for checkbox in component.html-

```
<md-checkbox #checkBox (keyup)="handleCheckBoxKeyUp($event,checkBox)" name="" value=""></md-checkbox>
```

Code for checkbox selection via spacebar in my component.ts-

```
handleKeyUp($event,checkBox: MdCheckBox){
    if ($event.code===32){
    checkBox.checked=true;
    }
}
```

When I hit spacebar,checkbox is being checked but it does not get unchecked on next hit of spacebar. That should happen consecutively.Any help would be much appreciated.

Also, I want to reuse this functionality in multiple pages. Let me know how that can be done.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very basic programming question.

Instead of setting the `checked` property to `true`, you want to invert its value everytime the spacebar is hit.

This is done using the `!` or logical `NOT` operator. In your case it will be:

```
checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
```

If checkbox is checked (or `true`), `!` will invert it and set `checked` to `false`.